# Protobuf timestamp getting auto converted

Tags: python, mongodb, timestamp, protocol-buffers, proto

I am reading timestamp strings of format '2014-11-09T01:00Z' from mongo and storing in a python  dict. But while retrieving same from the dict I see some of the strings got automatically converted to proto timestamp like  seconds: 1511047800.

I have no clue how could this happen. Any insights appreciated.

```
class SomeInfo:

__school_id_info = defaultdict(
    lambda: {'banned': -1,
             'school_boy': False,
             'teacher': False})

def __init__(self):
    mongo_connection_str = os.environ['MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING']
    mongo_db_name = os.environ.get('MONGO_DB_NAME', 'coll')
    mongo_dao = MongoDao(mongo_connection_str, mongo_db_name)
    mongo_collection_name = 'school'
    school_records = mongo_dao.find_records(mongo_collection_name)

    for school_details in school_records:
        self.__school_id_info['date'] = school_details['date']
    #If I print the __school_id_info here I see date as '2014-11-09T01:00Z' string format which is same as how it is in Mongo.
    self.__dict__ = self.__school_id_info

def get_info_for_both_students(self) -> dict:
    #while returning from here I see some as seconds: 1235192400  protobuff timestamp format and some still as it is
    # .I am  not doing any conversion to protobuf timestamp
    return self.__school_id_info
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please provide us with some code and a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.